# Magento sell when at least a number of people need the product

Tags: php, html, magento

I am trying to make this option to my magento store. People will go into the store and they will have to show interest for a product. When the number of interests reach 5 for example the product can be sold.

I will have to create a view2.phtml for this and add custom layout to a category so I can choose in which products I need this option. But how can this be done? Is there any plugin or way to achieve?

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far? your questions is vague - could you be more concrete (i.e. how do I keep track of product view counts, or I'm receiving error message X, what does it mean)?

Comment: I have tried to add a counter where people will click on and when the counter reach number 5 then those people will be able to buy the product. But this is not the correct way to do something like this. So if you have any other idea of how I can do something like this it would be nice to know

Answer (score 0):

You can add Custom Layout Updates (Product->Design) for each product.
By adding a rule like

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"> 
    <template>catalog/product/view2.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

the product page will be view2.phtml just for that single product.

Note that it is better to place this new file (view2.phtml) inside your own theme folder instead of using the base directory.